# DB2 select last day with a lot of data

Tags: db2

I have a very big table in DB2 with around 500 million rows

I need to select the last day only based on a `timestamp` column and other conditions

I did something like this, but it takes forever (about `10` minutes) to get the results, is there any other way to query this faster, I am not familiar with db2

`DTM` is a `timestamp` datatype

```
select a, b, c, d, e, DTM from  table1 
where e = 'I' and DTM > current timestamp - 1 days
```

Any help please

Comment: My guess is there is no index on DTM, so the entire 500 million row table has to be read.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - or an index starting with column `e`, or both.  Serg, this is a decent first start, although you should probably be doing `DTM >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 DAYS` (note the changed comparison - this has more to do with how ranges are conceptualized, and nothing to do with performance, though).  At least what you are doing is amenable to using an index in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Besides an index, another option may be range partitioning on this table.  If you could range partition by month, you would only have to scan the month, for example.  Even better if you could partition by day (and have the partitioning key in the index so you had partitioned index too).